# Is it a good idea to have a power plane and route power selectively?

Tags: power, eda

Hopefully not too general of a question but: in a 4 layer design with the following stackup:

Top

GND (solid plane)

Power (solid plane)

Bottom

Is it a bad idea, given the above, to ever route power traces on the top (rather than tapping it with a via close to the component?) This is given the power plane is used for some components, just not all.

And by bad idea I mean: are there technical disadvantages?

Comment: I mean...it's not a bad idea if you have one component that uses a different voltage and the regulator for that voltage is right beside it. I think you have a specific scenario in mind you're not telling us.

Answer (score 1):

If you want QUIET VDD for some ICs, then you need to isolate that local VDD node with a resistor (or inductor) to guarantee some series impedance in the filtering.

Couple months ago, a stackX question arose about ---- why do my 6 amplifier chains oscillate. Each chain was 10X/10X/buffer for 25 ohms (high current).

Turned out all the 18 highspeed opamps shared the same VDD+ and same VDD- node.

And with gain of 100X in each signal chain, with an output buffer driving 25 ohm (dual 50 ohm) loads, the transient currents made the shared_VDD (+ and -) provide feedback.

The finite PSRR, at high frequencies, was the problem at 100+ MHz.

Cure was to insert 10 ohms (TEN) from the global VDD node to the VDD pins (+ and -) of each opamp. I had suggested using ONE OHM. The questioner only had 10 OHMS, and 10 ohms worked very well.

In your case, identify where QUIET VDD is needed. Maybe you don't need quiet vdd.

Comment: I remember that question but forget how high the current was and the resulting voltage drop from the 1 or 10 Ohm resistor.